# When the button is a picture, the text also has a prescribed size and spacing. How to make the text appear in the middle of the picture through CSS?

Tags: css

I have a question feel troubled CSS settings need everyone's help -

requirements are as follows:
a picture of a button, the picture has a text
design draft marked above the button is the size of the picture must be 200px width of the text must be 26px
text In the middle of the picture, the upper and lower spacing between the picture and the picture is 8px. The example shown in the figure below needs to be achieved.

But I can’t do it anyway. I hope you can provide some solutions to let me know how to deal with this kind of demand. Thank you Everyone[image]

```css
.btn{
    display: inline-block;
    width: 200px;
    height: 100px;
    background-image: url('https://upload.cc/i1/2021/09/12/IX7D1d.png');
    background-size: cover;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: center center;
    background-size: 140%;
}

.txt{
    font-size: 26px;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 16px;
}
```

```html
<a class="btn" href="javascript:;">
    <p class="txt">send</p>
</a>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your background is misleading you to believe that it matches the button position and size (if you add a border to the `.btn` style you will see what I mean)

So if your background is yellow and need a blackborder better to style it, is faster than loading a button image and scale it.

```css
.btn{
    position: relative ;
    display: inline-block;
    width: 200px;
    height: 42px; /* 8 + 26 +8*/
    border: 5px solid black ;
    background-color: yellow ;
    border-radius: 25px ;
    
    /* to center the text vertically using flex*/
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-content: center;
    flex-direction: column;
}

.txt{
    font-size: 26px;
    text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<a class="btn" href="javascript:;">
    <p class="txt">send</p>
</a>
```

Answer (score 1):

first make sure no margin is defined by default by adding `margin: 0px;`

2ndly, Add a line-height property to it using `line-height: 1.5;`

There are several other ways, but this should be the fastest

```css
.btn{
    display: inline-block;
    width: 200px;
    height: 100px;
    background-image: url('https://upload.cc/i1/2021/09/12/IX7D1d.png');
    background-size: cover;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: center center;
    background-size: 140%;
}

.txt {
    font-size: 26px;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 16px;
    margin: 0px;
    line-height: 1.5;
}
```

```html
<a class="btn" href="javascript:;">
    <p class="txt">send</p>
</a>
```